# Bash script quitting after 30 minutes of inaction

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that acts as a wrapper to get-iplayer, that downloads BBC programmes. How can I have it quit itself after 30 minutes of inaction please? The source code of the script is at http://www.sharons.org.uk/2014/02/17/beeb-v3-0/

Comment: Define "inaction". If the script is simply blocking until `get-iplayer` exits, you would need some way of monitoring `get-iplayer` to know if it was actually doing anything or not.

Comment: I mean when it is just sitting there and not downloading anything, or could be waiting for a reply to a question that it has just asked, but you've gone to bed and left it running!

Comment: The `read` builtin can be given a default timeout by setting the value of `TMOUT`, but there is nothing (easy) you can do in general. `bash` has no way of knowing what `get-iplayer` is doing, only that it it still running. You would need to post your script for a more detailed answer.

Comment: Read about [TMOUT](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/tmout-exit-bash-shell-when-no-activity/).

Comment: Unfortunately it is 246 lines so it is impractical to post it here, which is why I gave a link to the source-code. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-t` parameter does this for you in `read`.

e.g.

```
read -t 5 -p "What is your name?"
```

This code waits for your input for 5 seconds as per the value of the `-t` parameter.

You can add the parameter in your script where `read` occurs.

Comment: Thanks, I've added '-t 1800' which should last for 30 minutes.